# Return datapoints over polygons using Geopandas

Tags: data-science, geospatial, data-mining, spatial, geopandas

I am trying to get what is the number of trips by each borough in NYC, I am using NYC Taxi Fare dataset and I have retrieved 1'500,000 datapoints. The problem is that the procedure is very very slow, are there others procedure to calculate these values, calculate number of trips por each borough. Thank you I will appreciate any comment or idea.

> Blockquote

```
count=0
results=[]
for index_boro, row_boro in boroughs_gpd.iterrows():
  count=0
  print(row_boro.boro_name)
  geom_boro = row_boro.geometry
  for index_points, row_points in gdf.iterrows():
    if (row_points.geometry.within(geom_boro)):
      count=count+1
  results.append((row_boro.boro_code,count))
  break
a = tuple(results)   
a
```

Comment: I did break after calculate the first borough.

Comment: read up on `geopandas.overlay` and `geopandas.sjoin`